# ASCII + Numpad combination for power 10

Tags: c#, math, language-agnostic

I am writing an app and I need to use power numbers in strings. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to type power 10 characters. I know that if I hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>0178</kbd>, the character "²" will appear, but how do I type things like <sup>3</sup> or even <sup>40</sup>?

I've tried looking online, but only see codes for "²" (and other, non-related ones). I've tried using the Character Map program in Windows but I couldn't find anything in there other than "²".

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. They were very helpful :)

Comment: Is this a programming question? or a typing question?

Comment: It's mainly a typing question in general - but - it's preventing me from continuing with my app. So unless I know how to write these little buggers down, I cannot continue with my app. @DavidYaw Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you're outputting these characters from the an application, it's not necessary to actually type them. See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make a superscript ten the same way you type it normally: with a one and a zero.

- Superscript 1: Alt 0185 or Alt +00B9: ¹
- Superscript 2: Alt 0178 or Alt +00B2: ²
- Superscript 3: Alt 0179 or Alt +00B3: ³
- Superscript 4: Alt +2074: ⁴
- Superscript 5: Alt +2075: ⁵
- Superscript 6: Alt +2076: ⁶
- Superscript 7: Alt +2077: ⁷
- Superscript 8: Alt +2078: ⁸
- Superscript 9: Alt +2079: ⁹
- Superscript 0: Alt +2070: ⁰

If you're writing code, the better way to refer to them in code is with the proper escape code. The syntax here is for C/C++/C#/Java, but other languages should have something similar.

- Superscript 1: "\u00B9"
- Superscript 2: "\u00B2"
- Superscript 3: "\u00B3"
- Superscript 4: "\u2074"
- Superscript 5: "\u2075"
- Superscript 6: "\u2076"
- Superscript 7: "\u2077"
- Superscript 8: "\u2078"
- Superscript 9: "\u2079"
- Superscript 0: "\u2070"

Comment: Superscript 4 through 0 do not work for me. They output: `→` `←` `∟` `↔` `▲` `▼` `▬` instead.

Comment: Make sure you're pressing the "+" key on the numeric keypad, and then the number. You may also have to adjust a registry setting, see here: http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe there is a Unicode character for the power of 10. Notepad allows you to enter text, and the Alt+NumPad keystrokes give you a way to enter a Unicode character. But to the best of my knowledge, the character you are looking for does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 exponent character is an extended ASCII character (253 decimal); there is no equivalent for 10. See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for a list of what's available in typical character sets.

Consider using Word (or any word processor, or Mathematica which makes entering formulas and "math notation" very easy, and you can execute it!) for this type of thing as Notepad isn't really up to the challenge. Every word processor I've used offers superscript (exponent) character styling, and some (including Word) offer a "formula editor."

Answer (score 1):

Did you try pressing "^" this symbol every time you want the number to appear as a power?

Comment: You mean, I can just type: `2^10`?

Comment: @dko - just a note: `^` in most C-style languages (including C#) is an XOR, not an exponent operation (though I don't see that this affects text formatting at all)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a superscript generator to copy/paste from. I'm having varying degrees of success for 0 and numbers higher than 4, depending on what I'm pasting into. It has to do with the character encoding of whatever tool you are pasting into. Tommy and David discuss this in the comments above.

https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator

The creator also made a subscript generator:
https://lingojam.com/SubscriptGenerator